# Time-independence of Hamiltonian of atomic chain

Tags: quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, condensed-matter

In the first chapter of Atland and Simons book he gives the Hamiltonian of the atomic chain
$$
H[\pi,\phi] = \int dx \Bigg(\frac{\pi^2}{2m} + \frac{k_sa^2}{2}(\partial_x\phi)^2\Bigg)
$$
After considering a right moving solution of the wave equation, which is say $\phi_+(x-vt)$, he concludes that the Hamiltonian is a time-independent expression, which is to write
$$
H[\pi,\phi] = k_sa^2\int dx \Big(\partial_x\phi(x)\Big)^2
$$
My question is how can we prove this without using Hamilton's equation of motions for the field ?